# FMDB SQLite doesn't show up in my device

Tags: ios, database, ipad, sqlite, fmdb

Again, I need someone's help. I am following the below tutorial for SQLite connection with FMDB wrapper:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/11/04/simple-sqlite-database-interaction-using-fmdb/

In the above tutorial, everything (creating a database and table, inserting, deleting) is done programmatically but everything works fine in simulator but when I use SQLite Manager add-on to make any insertion on the database (that was programmatically created in iOS), it doesn't show up in my testing device. Is there something that I am missing (like copying the file to my bundle) on my side? This is really driving me crazy. I am completely new to these.. Can anyone help me with this?

PS: I know I can use Core Data but for certain reasons I have to live with SQLite for this app. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is very strange, because there are no tricks about how to do this. If it works on the simulator, it generally works on the device. Can you provide more information about how you know it's not being generated on the device, perhaps show the code of where you open the database, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to (a) include the db in the bundle (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605072/sqlite-will-not-prepare-query-when-accessing-database-in-xcode/11605495#11605495) for screen snapshot of where the "copy bundle resources" can be found); and (b) [programmatically copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664043/unable-to-connect-sqlite-database-in-ios/11674730#11674730) db from bundle to documents. You can then open it from there.

Why it works on your simulator and not the device is a little curious. I can only imagine that you're reading from some fixed path, rather than programmatically retrieving the app's Documents folder?

**Update:**

I'd suggest checking your various return codes and make sure everything is ok.

I've taken your code sample and have (a) checked result of creation of `FMDatabase`; (b) checked result of `open`; (c) checked the result of `FMResultSet`, including the display of the sqlite error message; and (d) closed the result set:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DADatabase.sqlite"];

FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
NSAssert(database, @"Unable to create FMDatabase object");

NSLog(@"%@", database);

BOOL success = [database open];
NSAssert(success, @"Unable to open database");

FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM DrugList"];
NSAssert(results, @"Unable to create result set: %@", [database lastErrorMessage]);

while([results next]) {
    NSString *name = [results stringForColumn:@"Drugname"];
    [arrayToLoadDiseases addObject:name];
}

[results close]; 

[database close];
```

If you're running this in your simulator, you can go ahead and inspect the simulator's bundle and Documents folders if things don't go right, just to make sure everything is where it should be. You simulator's folder is something like "~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/" (replace the 5.1 with whatever version of your simulator you are using). You might have to unhide your `Library` folder, if you haven't already, by running the `chflags nohidden ~/Library` in a `Terminal` command-line window. Anyway, you can open up the simulator's database using Mac OS X's `sqlite3` command and make sure your table is ok.

A common mistake is to fail to [programmatically copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664043/unable-to-connect-sqlite-database-in-ios/11674730#11674730) the database properly, thus the `open` method will create a blank database, and `executeQuery` will fail saying that the table was not found.

Let me know what you find.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much Robert! You are right. The problem was only with copying the file into Documents folder. I used the code you've mentioned on the other post, it all worked! Thanks again for your help. It was a great learning all these times with SQLite. Wish I could give +100 :) TY..